# Passing an implicit typed variable: "var" to a function in C# and returning an array?

Tags: c#, linq, methods, implicit

I'm writing a function to break_up my main(). Specifically, in this function, I will be passing a "var" or implicit instance of an object. 1.But the compiler is not happy about that.2. Also its not happy about returning an array from this function as well.

Err msgs

1. } expected
2. The type or namespace name 'var' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

`public class string [] xml_to_array(string tag_name,  var select_range, XNamespace xmlns)`

```
{
        string [] ret_array=select_range.Descendants(xmlns+ tag_name)
                            .Select(elem => elem.Value).ToArray();
        return ret_array;
}
```

"var select_range" can be a IEnumerable from an instance of a LINQ/SQL stmt:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> select_range= from result in doc.Descendants(xmlns+ "Assessment")
                           where result.Element(xmlns + "Location").Value.ToLower().Contains(r)
                           select result;
```

or it can be an XDOCUMENT type:

```
 XDocument select_range = XDocument.Load("C:/Users/jake_lane/Documents/parser/ex.xml");
```

Comment: LINQ and LINQ to SQL are two different things.

Answer (score 3):

Why not change the parameter type to `IEnumerable<XElement>`:

```
public string [] xml_to_array(string tag_name, IEnumerable<XElement> select_range, XNamespace xmlns)
```

And change:

```
XDocument select_range = XDocument.Load
("C:/Users/jake_lane/Documents/parser/ex.xml");
```

to:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> select_range = XDocument.Load
("C:/Users/jake_lane/Documents/parser/ex.xml")
.Descendants();
```

Comment: Somehow, I'm getting double the actual size of the array returned. When I didn't use IEnumerable<XElement> ... to load the document, the size of the array is 1, when I do use it, it's size 2

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately I don't have enough code to really know what's happening there.

Comment: Ok I fixed it! I used .Elements() instead of Descendants(). Not sure why it fixed it. Do you know??

Comment: @jerryh91 You must have needed the child elements (`Elements()`) rather than the descendant elements (`Descendants()`) Basically `Elements()` will just give you direct children, not any grandchildren etc but `Descendants()` will give you matching nodes at any level.

Answer (score 1):

`var`  is only for you, the compiler know the type - so you can't use it in method signature

From [MSDN - var](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx)  :

> An implicitly typed local variable is strongly typed just as if you
>   had declared the type yourself, but the compiler determines the type

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use var for parameters in methods. The compiler must be able to determine what datatype to exchange var for.

You can also not have the class keyword in a method declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Generic answer:
Create two different methods with different signatures, one with IEnumerable and one with XDocument.  If both are similar, you can call the more generic version from the more specific version, or convert one type to the other type and return what is called from the other one passing in the new type.

Specific to XDocument and IEnumberable:
Unless of course, of the types (XDocument) can be implicitly converted to the other (IEnumberable), then just use the more specific type in your signature (IEnumberable).